# como mostrar un array, mediante post

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando insertar y enviar unos datos por medio de url, pero no tengo el resultado, con una variable en especifico.

```
require('conex.php');
mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($database) ;

if( isset($_POST["MM_insert"])){ 
  for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['id_foto']); $i++){
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO sms (id_foto, alumno, responsable1, responsable2, estado_sms, concepto, fecha, mobile) values ('".$_POST['id'][$i]."','".$_POST['nombre'][$i]."','".$_POST['dato1'][$i]."','".$_POST['dato2'][$i]."','".$_POST['estado'][$i]."','".$_POST['concepto'][$i]."','".$_POST['fecha'][$i]."','".$_POST['mobile'][$i]."') ") or die(mysql_error());
    $msg=$_POST['mensaje'];
    $mob=$_POST['mobile'][$i];

    header("Location: ../../enviosms.php?user=".$usuario."&pass=".$pass."&msg=".$msg."&telf=".print_r($mob, TRUE)."");

  }

}
```

Explico un poco el codigo,

Lo que hago aqui es recibir por medio de post , todo muy bien hasta ahi, pero cuando envio los mobiles y los capturo,mediante un array para capturarlos en linea como por ejemplo de tres numeros de telefono: (188997089881879865678918097655432) pero no me ha sido posible.

Lo que quisiera poder hacer es capturar estos números uno al lado del otro e incluirle la coma,(ejemplo 18899708988,18798656789,18097655432)
pero no lo he logrado, que puedo estar haciendo mal, alguna guía por favor y gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Crees posible que nos coloques un print_r de los datos que generas con el $_POST creo que de ahi puede venir todo el asunto, ya que no sabemos como envias los datos por el post y como los debes capturar en el for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gracias por las orientaciones, lo resolvi convirtiendo el array en una cadena , y funciono perfectamente, dejo el codigo por si le puede servir a alguien

```
require('conex.php');
mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($database) ;

if( isset($_POST["MM_insert"])){ 
  for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['id_foto']); $i++){
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO sms (id_foto, alumno, responsable1, responsable2, estado_sms, concepto, fecha, mobile) values ('".$_POST['id'][$i]."','".$_POST['nombre'][$i]."','".$_POST['dato1'][$i]."','".$_POST['dato2'][$i]."','".$_POST['estado'][$i]."','".$_POST['concepto'][$i]."','".$_POST['fecha'][$i]."','".$_POST['mobile'][$i]."') ") or die(mysql_error());
    $msg=$_POST['mensaje'];
    $mob=implode($_POST['mobile']);
    header("Location: ../../enviosms.php?user=".$usuario."&pass=".$pass."&msg=".$msg."&telf=".$mob."");

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

pasa tu variable como un arreglo al get

algo asi:

```
header("Location: ../../enviosms.php?user=".$usuario."&pass=".$pass."&msg=".$msg."&telf[]=".$mob);
```

saludos